# dynamically creating array in php

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to create arrays dynamically and then populate them by constructing array Names using variable but I am getting the following warnings

Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given
Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

For single array this method worked but for array of arrays this is not working. How should this be done?

```
<?php

for ($i = 1; $i <= 23; ++$i) 
{
        $word_list[$i] = array("1"); 
}


for ($i = 1; $i <= 23; ++$i) 
{
  $word = "abc";
  $arrayName = "word_list[" . $i . "]";
  if(!in_array($word, ${$arrayName})) 
  {
    array_push($$arrayName , $word);
  }
}


?>
```

Comment: try `echo $arrayName` and `echo $$arrayName` and see what you get. I bet it's something useless and null like the error message says.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are even trying to put array name in a variable and then de-reference that name?  Why not just do this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 23; ++$i) 
{
  $word = "abc";
  $arrayName = "word_list[" . $i . "]";
  if(!in_array($word, $word_list[$i])) 
  {
    array_push($word_list[$i] , $word);
  }
}
```

Comment: i guess the OP constructed this example for us and in reality, he does not have the name of the array (except for the string).

Comment: @Kaii possibly.  I just hate to see an over-engineered solution.  When a simple solution exists, why not just use it?

Comment: Why declare `$arrayName` at all?

Answer (score 3):

You get the first warning because your `$arrayName` variable is not actually an array, you made it into a string.

So instead of:

```
$arrayName = "word_list[" . $i . "]";
```

You should have this:

```
$arrayName = $word_list[$i];
```

You get your second warning because your first parameter is not an array.

So instead of:

```
array_push($$arrayName , $word);
```

You should have this:

```
array_push($arrayName , $word);
```

If you make these changes you will get an array that looks like this in the end:

```
$wordlist = array( array("1", "abc"), array("1", "abc"), ... ); // repeated 23 times
```

Answer (score 1):

And in the for loop, you are accessing the array the wrong way

Here is your corrected code

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 23; ++$i) 
{
  $word = "abc";
  $arrayName = $word_list[$i];
  if(!in_array($word, $arrayName)) 
  {
    array_push($arrayName , $word);
    $word_list[$i] = $arrayName;
  }

}
```

Comment: @vaichidrewar, Misunderstood the question, BUT NOW fixed with tested solution